# Which properties are preserved when extending a measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm interested in knowing which properties of a measure $\mu$ are preserved, when we extend that measure by the Carathéodory Extension Theorem.

Also, more specifically, imagine I've proved $\mu$ satisfies a certain property for all types of intervals where $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite on field $\mathcal{F}_0$. If I were to extend $\mu$ to the $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_0)$, would those properties be maintained to any subset of $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_0)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra you obtain from the Carathéodory Extension Theorem is usually larger than $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_0)$, because it contains all sets with zero outer measure.